# MySQL Query to join two select queries

Tags: mysql

I basically have one table

which  has the following columns api_key, business_name, status, trans_amount. each row corresponds to an attempt.
every business has a different api_key

now i want the following data

**Grouped by API KEY**, 
sum of trans_amount for each business,
sum of trans_amount for each business where status = PAID,
number of total attempts for each business,
number of paid attempts for each business

now these data i want in a single table! basically the prob is each column has a different condition that i have to work with

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I recommend using a `JOIN` http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database

Comment: i know i can use JOIN but this involves group by clause and its like i ll have to join the result of two queries one without any condition and other condition status = PAID

Comment: I see, have you tried using a `LEFT JOIN`. This should have the same effect as the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: but how can i have two different conditions for different columns in the output data set?

Comment: it was easy with a single condition but here i have to get total number then i have to get ones which are paid in the same output set

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you consider case expressions ?

```
SELECT API_KEY,
       SUM( trans_amount ) As Total_Amount,
       SUM( CASE WHEN status ='PAID' THEN trans_amount ELSE 0 END ) As Paid_Amount,
       COUNT( * ) As total_attempts,
       SUM( CASE WHEN status ='PAID' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) As Paid_Attemtpts
FROM table
GROUP BY API_KEY
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked! I tried case expressions but messed up with the syntax and was getting something completely different

Comment: Use `IF` function if you don't like case expressions, see this link for the syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if. But I reccommend to use case expressions because they are ANSI SQL compliant and work on all DBMS, while `IF` function is MySql specific.